# NullPointerException on assigning value of another variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, variables, java-8, nullpointerexception

I am reading a value from `application.yml` file:
This is a global variable.

```
@Value("${config.key}")
    public String variable;
```

for My use case I need to the value of this variable to another global variable:

```
String secondVariable = variable;
```

logs show that the key is stored inside the variable but I assign secondVariable the value of first it gives null.
The `secondVariable` need to be global as I need to assign it a updated value when the scheduler runs.
What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After the Constructor call, Java initialize member variable so

```
variable = null
String secondVariable = variable
secondVariable = null
```

the variable is initialized after context initialization if you are working with spring.

Solution :

if secondVariable has the same scope as variable you should use the same annotation :

```
@Value("${config.key}")
    public String secondVariable;
```

Comment: thanks! but actually what I wanted to do was use the ```variable``` the first time the program runs and then use the ```secondVariable``` for the rest of the execution. Again use the variable only if the application is down and restarts. I solved this by just creating a function which takes both ```variable``` and ```secondVariable``` as parameter and return me the string according to my logic. Made life easier. thanks for the help though! much appreciated.